# Problem with z-index on CSS Bootstrap 4 drop down only on full screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Problem with CSS Bootstrap 4 drop down (Youth Bowling Canada) not activating hyperlinks on full screen.  However if you were to shrink the screen to have the hamburger dropdown it works fine.

http://www.bowlingingp.com/new/

I've tried adding z-index:9999; to the CSS on the dropdown class but it doesn't seem to work.

The hyperlinks should work when in full screen on the drop down menus as they do when the screen is shrunk to small size.

I think it has something do with the scroller on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right. It is a `z-index` issue.

Your slider with class `da-slider` and your dropdown container belong to different stacking groups. So set the `z-index` property to `-1`.

```
.da-slider {
  ...
  z-index: -1;
  ...
}
```

**PS:** Truth is you've got alot going on in your app.
This is a beautiful resource to understanding z-index property: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: I tried adding the z-index to the .da-slider but then the whole slider disappeared.  Too bad there wasn't a program that could tell you what each layer of the website is on.  It would make it much easier lol.  Thanks for your help, I will check into that link you gave me!

Comment: Please do, it's very comprehensive